# SQL Server: remove trailing spaces from CHAR column when value is retrieved by setting a parameter or configuring server

Tags: sql-server

I have a program that until yesterday has been using only with MySQL. From today i have been told that the program will have to be compatible also with SQL Server. Since I am using an ORM (Hibernate) almost everything worked out fine, except for a `CHAR` column.

In fact, MySQL and SQL Server (configured as they are on my machine), handle the `CHAR` column differently. My program works fine with the MySQL way of handling `CHAR`, which is:

> The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare
>   when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255.
>   When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the
>   specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are
>   removed unless the PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode is enabled.

On the other hand, SQL Server adds trailing spaces to the value when storing it and does not remove them when it retrieves it.

So, my question is: am I forced to edit my program in order to handle such difference or there is some SQL Server parameter or configuration of the SQL Server that I don't know about that can simulate the MySQL way of handling `CHAR`?

Comment: CHAR has behavior as defined by ANSI SQL which SQL Server follows.  If you don't want padding, then perhaps you can use VARCHAR instead?  You can somewhat control ansi padding behavior using this knob, but I don't think it does quite what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-padding-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Actually this sounds like exactly what i am looking for! The only thing i cannot understand  is: this command will affect all schemas on the server or just my schema?

Comment: I believe it is a session-level property that works when you create new tables, IIRC.

Comment: ok...let me try it and get back at you... i probably just need to set the property that you have mentioned through the connection string, like this https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-set-sql-server-options-ansi-nulls-ansi-padding-ansi-warnings-using-hibernate/2073